# Curl PUT upload succeeding despite 404 response

Tags: curl, file-upload, webserver, ngrok

I am forwarding to a webserver with ngrok, and I want to be able to upload a file to it. When running `curl <my_ngrok_subdomain>.com --upload-file test.txt` the curl appears to successfully upload, however I'm unsure why it's returning a 404:

Here's non-verbose which makes me think it's succeeding:

```
$ curl  blahblahblah.ngrok.io --upload-file test.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    49  100    35  100    14     30     12  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    42
Tunnel blahblahblah.ngrok.io not found
```

So it *looks* like the file is successfully uploading, however here's the curl with verbose enabled, which has me unsure...

```
$curl --verbose blahblahblah.ngrok.io --upload-file test.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying XX.XX.XX.XX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to blahblahblah.ngrok.io (XX.XX.XX.XX) port 80 (#0)
> PUT /test.txt HTTP/1.1
> Host: blahblahblah.ngrok.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 14
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
* Done waiting for 100-continue
  0    14    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0} [14 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Length: 35
< Content-Type: text/plain
< 
{ [35 bytes data]
100    49  100    35  100    14     30     12  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    42
* Connection #0 to blahblahblah.ngrok.io left intact
Tunnel blahblahblah.ngrok.io not found.
```

Is it possible for a curl upload to succeed despite returning a 404?

Comment: It looks like it happened *after* your upload.  I don't know what `Tunnel blahblahblah.ngrok.io not found` means, but that's where it happened.

Comment: So does that mean that doing a PUT with a curl will write file before even receiving a response?

Comment: Don't know.  You'd have to try it.